# Change the image of a CCSprite programmatically using cocos2d v3.x in Swift

Tags: swift, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I know there a many questions regarding this topic but they are all very old and I can't find a resource explaining how to do it in cocos2d v3.x and in Swift.  I have some PNGs in a folder in SpriteBuilder and I have made it a Smart Sprite Sheet but I don't know what to do from there.  The other questions' answers made me believe this would work:

```
hero.setSpriteFrame("image.png")
```

I have tried it but there is no method called that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SWIFT CODE**

```
var hero = CCSprite.spriteWithImageNamed("hero.png") as CCSprite;
var frame = CCSpriteFrame.frameWithImageNamed("ImageName.png") as CCSpriteFrame
hero.spriteFrame = frame;
```

**Obj.C CODE**

```
 #define SPRITE_CACHE ([CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache])

 carSprite.spriteFrame = [SPRITE_CACHE spriteFrameByName:@"redCar.png"]
```

Comment: Great! It worked perfectly!  Just needed to add the folder name before ImageName.png